# Unicode program, but linker wants WinMain instead of wWinMain

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, winmain

I am trying to convert one of my older C++ programs from ANSI to Unicode. I am using Visual Studio 2022. After I did all changes in the source code, my program compiles without errors but it does not link, saying that WinMain is expected, but I've got wWinMain.

LIBCMTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

My declaration:
`int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR cmdline, int nCmdShow)`

So my question is: How does it decide whether to call WinMain or wWinMain? It seems the source code is correct, just some project settings need to be changed.

---

Maybe the root of my issue is somewhere else, so I try to add more information:

The program consists of a few static libraries (.lib) + main exe project , all of them C++ projects in the same .sln solution. So I set "Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set" in the project configuration of all of my projects in this solution.

After I converted the source code to use wchar_t or TCHAR and all related functions for Unicode, all lib projects compile without errors. But some .cpp files the main project do not compile and the compilation errors show that TCHAR = char. Since the TCHAR definition is based on whether _UNICODE is defined, I manually added preprocessor definition _UNICODE and also UNICODE. Now everything compiles without errors. But it does not link - it wants WinMain, but I've got wWinMain in my code.

So again, my question is: How does it decide whether to call WinMain or wWinMain?

MSDN says:

> How does the compiler know to invoke wWinMain instead of the standard
> main function? What actually happens is that the Microsoft C runtime
> library (CRT) provides an implementation of main that calls either
> WinMain or wWinMain.

This does not really answer the question. How the compiler decides which one of them to call?
What more do I need to set in the project configuration in addition to "Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set"?

Comment: Please show your code. The Visual Studio CRT finds and uses one of the both functions. Your code seems to miss both.

Comment: @273K My declaration is: int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR cmdline, int nCmdShow)

Comment: Just a declaration, missing implementation?

Comment: Just tried `#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR cmdline, int nCmdShow) {
}` in 1.cc and `cl.exe 1.cc` - works well.

Comment: No `wWinMain` definition will also trigger Error lnk2019. Try providing an example that reproduce the problem.

Comment: When I create a new project from template in Visual Studio, it works. That's why it is a mystery, what is different? I bet there is something broken with vcxproj file, this one was created years ago with an older Visual Studio.

Comment: One special thing in my program: Function wWinMain is not in the main project, it is in one of those lib static libraries. It worked this way before I switched to Unicode. Can this be the problem?

Comment: OK, I found the solution. It chooses between WinMain and wWinMain automagically, but the function cannot be in a static library (lib). If it is defined in a library, it accepts only MBCS WinMain. This looks to me like a defect of MSVC or Linker.

Comment: @AlKepp   "This looks to me like a defect of MSVC or Linker" - Or maybe (the simplest explanation); you just don't know how to use the tools properly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl excuse me? That's why I am asking this question here. This behavior of compiler/linker does not seem to be explained in MSDN.

Comment: @AlKepp I'm aware of that (why you are asking). But blaming the tools - like you did when saying that it was probably a MSVC or linker defect is a common reaction when someone just doesn't know how to use the tools correctly.  "The tool doesn't do what I want so it must be broken" - whoops; the tool works; I just didn't know how to use it.   Very common. Just because it's not explained in the documentation doesn't mean that the tool is broken.

Comment: @AlKepp - It's about the odds. Millions of people write Windows programs with Unicode support, and it works. Your program did not. What are the odds that your program is correct, and the tools have severe bugs?

Comment: @BoP this is not about odds, did you read the discussion? I already found what is wrong. During years, I already reported many bugs in MS build tools, this is pretty common. They are so big and have many features. Many edge cases are not covered. Since this one has a workaround, I doubt anybody will bother fixing it, so I'd say it is a waste of time trying to open a bug ticket for it in github.

Comment: @JesperJuhl please stop attacking me personally. I wrote "it seems like a defect", because it really seems like that. Literally IT SEEMS. And since I also proved there is uncovered edge case in Linker, I think there is nothing more to discuss here. I need to wait 3 days before I can write answer to my own question. This is the rule of stackoverflow, so now I am waiting and I will post the answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I found out the problem is in the fact my `wWinMain` is in a library. As I mentioned, I have a few static libraries (.lib) in the solution. So I made a simple test application which proves it.

My test program looks like this:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
    
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE, _In_ LPTSTR, _In_ int) { }
```

If this code is in the main application (.exe), it can be compiled in either MBCS or Unicode without any issue. The `_tWinMain` is translated to `WinMain` or `wWinMain` respectively and it is linked successfully.

But if I put the same code to a static library (.lib), the linker does not work as expected. MBCS works, it means it can find the `WinMain` and call it. And it works. But Unicode case does not work, the linker does not find my `wWinMain`, and then it outputs that confusing error message about missing `WinMain`.

**Solution:**

Although it seems as a bug or a design flaw of the Microsoft's linker, there is a simple workaround: I simply renamed my method in the library to `xWinMain` and added a proxy method called `_tWinMain` to the main project (.exe) which calls my `xWinMain`. And everything nicely works both in MBCS and Unicode.

(Tested with C++ toolset from Visual Studio 2015 and 2022.)